# Expecting numeric Error while importing data

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

while I try to import my dataset from excel on R using `readxl::read_excel`, I receive this error:

```
1: In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  ... :
  Expecting numeric in K14 / R14C11: got a date
```

Repeated for more than 50 times!
Can somebody help figure out why this is happening?
Thank you all

Comment: Which function and from which package are you using? Is it the `read_excel` function?

Comment: And that's a warning (or 50 warnings), not an error.  It just means that column K in your excel file contains numbers up until row 14, where you have a date. You can't mix data classes (formats), so go into that excel file and decide what format column K should really be: date or numeric.

Comment: I think that your sheet name contains space.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you have different variable types in the same column. You can always use the `coltypes='text'` option to get stuff imported and then sort it in R.